# react-hook-forms not validating react-select control with a defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am working on a form using react-hook-form, I needed a searchable select so I created a component using react-select.  My problem is, I am passing a default value on load and if I use `trigger()` to validate the field, I get an invalid on the `<Select>`.. this `getValues()` it pulls the correct value..  If I select a new value in the dropdown, it works.. just won't accept a default value..

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-liskov-lyump) if anyone has time to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Put your default value in the `defaultValues` prop provided by react-hook-form instead:

```
const formMethod = useForm<Address>({
  defaultValues: {
    state: options.find(({ value }) => value === "OH")
  }
});
```

And remove the `defaultValue` prop in the `Select` component. react-hook-form can only validate your data if it's aware of the `defaultValues`. Passing the default value directly to the `Select` is the same as not passing anything at all since it's react-hook-form who control the validation logic:

```
<Select
  {...props}
  // defaultValue={options.find(({ value }) => value === props.state)}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I ended up using setValue which fixed my problem.

Comment: @Dennis `setValue` just tells RHF to register the value again after the first render, this works but is not the most optimized solution. You should use the `defaultValues` provided by the RHF API because it's the intended way of setting the default values.